# I want to mask a data from mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a task where My app's `DELETE` api should not perform the actual delete on the mongodb document rather mask it from getting queried (for all the read queries). Currently my schema looks like below

```
Users [collection]
 |__ John [document]
       |__ id: 123
       |__ role: manager
       |__ enable: true  [masking key]
 |__ Jenny
       |__ id: 124
       |__ role: employee
       |__ enable: false
```

for now I am querying a subset of documents having `enable: True` however, it is not very efficient. I am planning change the model to

```
Users [collection]
 |__ John [document]
       |__ id: 123
       |__ role: manager
       |__ enable: true
Users-disable
 |__ Jenny
       |__ id: 124
       |__ role: employee
       |__ enable: false
```

having a separate collection for disable documents and only query the `Users` collection for documents.
I am also wondering if there is an existing option/mechanism in mongodb to the above or mask the documents from getting queried ?

Cheers,
DD.

Comment: What you may look for is creating an [index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-single/create-single-field-index/) on the `enabled` field. That way if the field is used in the filtering criteria mongodb can automatically use the index. This saves you the maintenance of another collection just for inactive users.